# What's the best way to test a specific revision with TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Let's say I have committed a revision locally, no pushing (let's call it r1_master). I created an executable based on that revision. I started working on something else which I have been committing locally to a new branch, again no pushing (let's call it r2_branch). Now I want to go back to r1_master, so that I can debug something that went wrong with the executable. However, I do not want to lose the changes from r2_branch, I simply want to debug r1_master, possibly applying some changes to fix it (commit them as r2_master possibly), then go back to the local branch, loading the changes from r2_branch (which will not have r2_master unless I merge).

1. How do I set my working copy so that the source code is exactly as it was in r1_master, without changes from r2_branch but also without erasing those changes forever?
2. How do I commit a fix to master as r2_master?
3. How can I load the changes from r2_branch again?

Bear in mind I want to do all of this locally, without pushing anything. Is that even possible? If not, the only changes I can push are the r2_branch ones, but wouldn't they require me to also push r1_master into the remote master?

I come from a TortoiseSVN background where I would just create patches for my local changes. I don't even know how to create patches in TortoiseGit or if there's a better way to do things. Thank you for your patience and responses!

EDIT1: Would it be best if I did a mixed reset back to r0_master, then a select commit to r1_branch of the changes I had for r2_branch, then push that commit, switch from branch to master and commit r1_master and be able to test it without having the changes from r1_branch? Then whenever I'm happy with r1_master, I can commit a fix to r2_master, maybe push r1 and r2 to master, then switch back to r1_branch to work on the separate feature?

Comment: I would recommend learning git basics. Like "what is a DVCS?" and "branching in git".

Comment: 1. Look up what git is, what a commit is, and then what checkout does ---
2. Just commit when on the r2_master branch ---
3. Checkout r2_branch

Comment: Watch https://youtu.be/1ffBJ4sVUb4

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks! My main doubt is, will my local commit to r2_branch be lost at any point? Will it get lost if I checkout r1_master before pushing? Will it get lost if I commit r2_master?

Comment: No, commiting to one branch will not affect another. Watch the video ;)

Comment: As a sort of general rule, all *commits* (in Git or any other VCS) are sacrosanct: never to be changed, and never to be removed without some explicit instruction by the user. (Even then, in Git especially, once a commit has made it to some other repository, it's like a bad virus, it keeps coming back. To really get rid of it you must manually remove it from *every* repository.)

Comment: Yes it is worth reading about the RefLog vs log file too. If you do something that worries you locally, just view RefLog and go back to where you feel comfortable.  I too get issues with viewing the log file and having the ability to "Switch", "Reset", "Rebase" and "Cherry Pick" .